# Can Jaxb automatically map objects?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an xml structure going like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<nesProfiles>
    <group>
        <baseIpAddress>10.241.1.1</baseIpAddress>
        <endIpAddress>10.241.1.125</endIpAddress>
        <profileName>VCX</profileName>
    </group>
    <group>
        <baseIpAddress>10.241.1.126</baseIpAddress>
        <endIpAddress>10.241.2.250</endIpAddress>
        <profileName>GT</profileName>
    </group>
    <properties>
        <profileName>GT</profileName>
        <serialNumberPrefix>GtSN</serialNumberPrefix>
        <firmwareVersion>GtFW</firmwareVersion>
        <hardwareType>GtHW</hardwareType>
        <productName>GtPN</productName>
        <portNumber>6</portNumber>
        <portBaseName>Port</portBaseName>
        <assembly>GtA</assembly>
    </properties>
    <properties>
        <profileName>VCX</profileName>
        <serialNumberPrefix>VcxSN</serialNumberPrefix>
        <firmwareVersion>VcxFW</firmwareVersion>
        <hardwareType>VcxHW</hardwareType>
        <productName>VcxPN</productName>
        <portNumber>7</portNumber>
        <portBaseName>Port</portBaseName>
        <assembly>VcxA</assembly>
    </properties>
</nesProfiles>
```

And i have the three following classes

```
@XmlRootElement( name = "properties" )
@XmlAccessorType( XmlAccessType.FIELD )
    public class NesProperties {

        private String profileName;
        private String serialNumberPrefix;
        private String firmwareVersion;
        private String hardwareType;
        private String productName;
        private String portBaseName;
        private String assembly;
        private int portNumber;
    }
```

.

```
@XmlRootElement( name = "group" )
@XmlAccessorType( XmlAccessType.FIELD )
    public class NesGroup {
        private String baseIpAddress;
        private String endIpAddress;
        private String profileName;
    }
```

.

```
@XmlRootElement( name = "nesProfiles" )
@XmlAccessorType( XmlAccessType.FIELD )
public class NesProfiles {

    @XmlElement( name = "properties" )
    private List<NesProperties> profiles = new ArrayList<NesProperties>();

    @XmlElement( name = "group" )
    private List<NesGroup> groups = new ArrayList<NesGroup>();
}
```

So a NesGroup object must be mapped to NesProperties one, currently i am doing this association by Java code by checking the profile name in the group element and putting the entry  in a hashmap of the NesProfiles object. I would like to know if it's possible to do that directly through JAXB with an xml structure like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<nesProfiles>
    <group>
        <baseIpAddress>10.241.1.1</baseIpAddress>
        <endIpAddress>10.241.1.125</endIpAddress>
        <properties>VCX</properties>
    </group>
    <group>
        <baseIpAddress>10.241.1.126</baseIpAddress>
        <endIpAddress>10.241.2.250</endIpAddress>
        <properties>GT</properties>
    </group>
    <properties>
        <profileName>GT</profileName>
        <serialNumberPrefix>GtSN</serialNumberPrefix>
        <firmwareVersion>GtFW</firmwareVersion>
        <hardwareType>GtHW</hardwareType>
        <productName>GtPN</productName>
        <portNumber>6</portNumber>
        <portBaseName>Port</portBaseName>
        <assembly>GtA</assembly>
    </properties>
    <properties>
        <profileName>VCX</profileName>
        <serialNumberPrefix>VcxSN</serialNumberPrefix>
        <firmwareVersion>VcxFW</firmwareVersion>
        <hardwareType>VcxHW</hardwareType>
        <productName>VcxPN</productName>
        <portNumber>7</portNumber>
        <portBaseName>Port</portBaseName>
        <assembly>VcxA</assembly>
    </properties>
</nesProfiles>
```

And having the the group object directly having the NesProperties object as a class attribute.

```
@XmlRootElement( name = "group" )
@XmlAccessorType( XmlAccessType.FIELD )
public class NesGroup {
  private String baseIpAddress;
  private String endIpAddress;
  private String profileName;
  private NesProperties nesProperties;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this with [`@XmlID`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlID.html)/[`@XmlIDREF`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlIDREF.html). Something like:

```
public class NesGroup {
  private String baseIpAddress;
  private String endIpAddress;
  private String profileName;
  @XmlIDREF
  private NesProperties nesProperties;
}
```

And:

```
   public class NesProperties {

        @XmlID
        private String profileName;
        private String serialNumberPrefix;
        private String firmwareVersion;
        private String hardwareType;
        private String productName;
        private String portBaseName;
        private String assembly;
        private int portNumber;
    }
```

See also [id resolvers](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2005/08/pluggable_ididr.html).